# include script not found using npm version of angulajs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I install angular via npm and in my public/index.html I do

```
<script src="/node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

And it's 404 in chrome console, any clue how can I include the script properly?

Comment: Do you have node_modules in root directory of your http server?

Comment: If you can show us your directory structure that will help

Answer (score 1):

Your `node_modules` folder is very likely not publicly accessible.

You have different options to solve this, including

- bundling your angular library with your code into a single script file, e.g. using [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/),
- placing the `angular.js` file in the `public` folder next to your `index.html` and embedding it from there and
- loading the angular library from a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network), e.g.:

  ```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  ```

Which option is the most suitable depends heavily on your use case.

Comment: I just follow what is instructed here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular

Comment: That's fine, however your server setup needs to support that. Currently, it seems like it doesn't.

Comment: I use express generator, clash or what?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) to load AngularJS in your project:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>`

Recommend Reading: [Why use a Content Delivery Network (CDN)?](https://gtmetrix.com/why-use-a-cdn.html)